# removing item from array und updating child component with the correct array lenght

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to implement a LIKE functionality on a list of products, I have a Redux state that on every Liked item adds the item to the list. But when i click the same item again i want that item to be removed from the Liked list. It actually seems that it works when i follow the state, but in my UI i have a child component that keeps tract of all liked items and it does not reflect the actions.

Here is my Liked component:

```
function LikeProduct (props) {

    const [like, setLike] = useState(false);
    const { product, setLikedProducts, removeLikedProduct } =  props;

    const handleLike = () => {
        return like ? (setLike(false), removeLikedProduct(product)) : (setLike(true), setLikedProducts(product));
    }

    return (
        <div className="LikeProduct">
            <Button 
                className={like ? "LikeProduct__like" : "LikeProduct__button"} 
                variant="link"
                onClick={handleLike}>
                <FaRegThumbsUp />
            </Button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

this component is imported into a Card component like so:

```
<LikeProduct product={product.title} />
```

it passes the name of the product that is liked by title;

my Action:

```
export function removeLikedProduct (product) {
    return {
        type: REMOVE_LIKED_PRODUCT,
        product
    }
}
```

my Reducer:

```
const setLikedProductReducer = (state=[], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_LIKED_PRODUCT:
            return state.concat(action.product)
        case REMOVE_LIKED_PRODUCT:
            // debugger;
            state.splice(state.indexOf(action.product), 1);
            return state;
        default:
            return state    
    }
}

export default setLikedProductReducer;
```

now I have this Header component where i mapPropsToSate:

```
function Header (props) {

    const [list, showList] = useState(false);
    const { liked } = props;

    const handleLikedList = () => {
        showList(true);
    }


    return (
        <div className="Header">
            <Navbar variant="light" bg="light">
                <Navbar.Brand>Troll</Navbar.Brand>

                <Button 
                    className="Header__likedList"
                    variant="link"
                    onClick={handleLikedList}>
                        <FaRegThumbsUp /> 
                        <span>{ liked.length }</span>
                </Button>
                {/* { list ? <div>TROLL</div> : null} */}
            </Navbar>
        </div>
      );
}
```

The problem is here `<span>{ liked.length }</span>`this does not reflect the state so the length is always maximum length if i remove 1 item it does not reflect in the UI but it does show in redux state that the item is removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your initial state object, state = {} . Then every time when  you mutate the state in your reducers, you have to return a new copy of the state. For example when you add a new item to the existing items in the state:

```
return {...state, products: [...state.products, payload]}
```

And when you remove the item

```
return {...state, products: state.products.filter(item => item !== payload)}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the replay i mean everything in the state looks like it works just fine its just the UI isynt getting updated no idea why